# IsEnabled property Background Colour is not changed in Wpf

Tags: telerik, wpf-controls

In my WPF  textbox when IsEnabled=false the background color is Gray..but this background color has not set in anywhere.when i set

```
  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
```

it doesnt work.when i changed IsEnabled="true" in properties,i could change the Background color.
can anyone please explain why background prorerty is not working for IsEnabled="False"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you need to update Border's background which is inside TextBox template. So, you can override template for you text box and set proper background there, in triggers section.

All default TextBox templates you could find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <Border 
        Name="Border"
        CornerRadius="2" 
        Padding="2"
        Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="1" >
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```